# How do `Vogel`, `hör` and `Trinken` relate to `Katze`?

Tags: phrase, saying

> ..falls du einen Vogel siehst hör auf zu Trinken..
> es ist eine Katze.

[image]

Source: https://debeste.de/309205/falls-du-einen-Vogel-siehst-h-r-auf-zu-Trinken

I know it literally means 'if you see a bird stop drinking, it is a cat', but what is the trick?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to language issues. Btw.: Stop drinking. ;)

Comment: *If you see a bird, stop drinking* = *wenn du einen Vogel siehst, hör auf zu trinken*; *if you see a bird stop drinking …* = *wenn du einen Vogel aufhören siehst zu trinken* (awkward, better: *wenn du siehst, wie ein Vogel aufhört zu trinken*).

Comment: (So the issue is that *if you see a bird(,) stop drinking* is ambiguous in English, but the German example cited is not.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no trick, just a funny picture.

If you're only casually glancing at the picture, you might think you see a black bird: One of the bird's eyes is looking at you, and the beak is pointing to the right. But if you look more closely, you realize it's a cat, the alleged beak is the cat's ear, and the second eye of the cat is just not that prominent.

So the idea of the text is just literally what it says: If you think this picture shows a bird, you should stop drinking (alcohol), because it's a picture of a cat.

Comment: Oh, I thought if the bird stops drinking it becomes a cat. I was thinking in the wrong direction, and it is indeed a cat.